# Python import (Could be python or Lego Mindstorms libs)

Tags: python, import, nonetype, lego-mindstorms

I'll start this by saying I'm not the most familiar with python, and this issue could be a more general python thing that I don't get (i.e. a glaringly obvious duplicate).

In the python bindings for the ev3, a motor is referenced like this:

```
# hardware.py #
import ev3dev.ev3 as ev3
motor = ev3.LargeMotor('outA')
motor.connected
```

Where 'outA' is the output port on the robot that the motor is connected to.

If I then do:

```
$:python hardware.py
```

I get no issues and I can use the motor normally. However, if I write a new file

```
# do_something.py # 
from hardware import *
```

I get an error:

```
Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <bound method    LargeMotor.__del__ of <ev3dev.core.LargeMotor object at 0xb67d2fd0>> ignored
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is it a python thing or an ev3 thing?

My reason for wanting to import in this way is so that I can do all of the hardware setup in one file (a sizeable chunk of code) and then import this to the files that actually make the robot perform tasks.

I know that NoneType is the type of None in python, I just don't know why a direct compile works but an import doesn't.

**1st Edit**:

Ok, so I compiled it as:

```
$:python hardware.py do_something.py
$:python do_something.py
```

And this gave no errors.

However, upon request, I've added more code, hardware.py is the same:

```
# do_something.py #
from hardware import *
counter = 0
while True:
  if (counter >= 1000):
    break
  motor.run_direct(duty_cycle_sp = 20)
  counter += 1
```

I.e. run the motor at a cycle speed of 20 until we've been through a thousand loop iterations.This works, and runs until the loop breaks and the script ends. The same NoneType error is then given and the motor continues to run even though the script has finished. The behaviour is the same with a KeyboardInterrupt. There is no traceback given, just that error message.

Comment: do `import hardware` instead of `from hardware import *`

Comment: I did this and got the same error as before

Comment: Please post the full stackstrace. For some reason the LargeMotor destructor doesn't work and produce the error that you have. And the destructor is probably called because your script ends. If you add some code in your do_something.py after the import, does that code work ?

Comment: See edit above. I can manipulate the motor, and then I get the same NoneType error when the script ends and the motor continues to run (even though execution is finished)

Comment: FWIW you're not (really) compiling, you're executing the code with `python hardware.py do_something.py`.

Comment: This looks a lot like an issue that I recently had with `selenium`, though, where Python was shutting down and the underlying lib was trying to do something with an already gone object. I suspect that's what's happening here with the `TypeError` on `__del__`. That means it's trying to call the `motor.__del__` method (probably) but it's not able to. What happens if you explicitly put `del motor` at the end of `hardware.py` (not indented, after the `while` loop)?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the delay. This makes sense, I don't have access to the kit just now so I'll try when I get access again, thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, python is a language at which it's codes are formed from words, and on the other hand the Lego Mindstorms "language" is formed of simple blocks. That said, logically the two languages cannot be mixed together and have nothing in common. And with having vast experience with both, I never found any thing in common between them.

Comment: I meant to close this question as I never found an answer and no longer have access to the equipment. Thank you for responding. I was using the ev3dev interface with python bindings. I know the mindstorms software you're talking about with program "blocks". I thought it could have been the issue suggested by Wayne Werner above, where python and the ev3dev library weren't interacting properly, however, I didn't get a chance to check.